# Redirect everything from one Wordpress installation to another WP blog

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 different WP-installations (blogs) on my site (a html site) in 2 different folders (blog1 and blog2).

I would need to permanently redirect everything on blog1, with all it's posts, to the index page of the other blog.

So basically I want to redirect everything from:

www.site.com/blog1/
including all posts ex. www.site.com/blog1/post-about-something/

to:

www.site.com/blog2/

What would be the best solution? Any plugins? If made by htaccess, should it be from www.site.com or www.site.com/blog1/ (In the WP folder)?

Thank you
Stefan

Comment: Hi Stefan, what have you tried already? Have you Ggoogled for an answer to this question?

Comment: This is straightforward rule if you search you will get the answer.